# Using both Angular routeProvider and Express routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, http, express

I'm trying to make angular's routeProvider to manage all the routes of my app. I define my routes accordingly in the app.js file of angular (client side):

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module("Crowdsourcing", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/single/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber", {
            templateUrl: "/views/single.html'",
            controller: "ListingCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
});
}());
```

However, when writing a URL (e.g. /single) on the browser that request is tried to be handled by my backend express/node api. Thus, it is not found because the backend routes are for example /api/foo. How can I make sure Angular's routeProvider always manages my requests?

And more important what is the basic flow of the application? When Client writing a URL how does the application knows whether the url is handled by express js or by routeProvider  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you distinguish URLs which are handled by the angular app from the express URLs by using a `#` sign between hostname and page URL.

For example:

If you want to request an URL from the backend you would call:
`http://host.com/api/foo/`

Instead if you want to request an URL from the angular app you would call: `http://host.com/#/single`

So if you want to call the angular app URL you have add the `#` sign.

This is a very important fact you need to keep in mind when working with single page applications.

**Update:**

Have a look at this seed project: https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed

It uses the a similar technology stack as your project. This should make it more clear for you.

Comment: but where should I call:
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/ListingCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/services/ListingService.js"></script>
?

Comment: I don't get your question? What do you want to do with the script tags?

Comment: I meant where should I load the app.js ? In which view should I store the script tag?

Comment: You need to have a base view in your express app where you load your angular app. Ideally this view should be reachable via the base URL '/'. Just create a route for that and provide a simple HTML page where you initialise `ng-app` etc. I have put a link to a seed project using the same stack as you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my app doesn't single page application.Is it matter ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does matter. What do you plan to achieve with `$routeprovider` and client-side routing, if you don't have an SPA?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue few days ago. The problem is, even when you make a server call for data it redirects it to client side routing and searches in `$routeProvider`.

You need to make sure you add something like below code in your `server.js`.
It means when ever there is a call starting with `/api` then it will redirect it to the routes in server side instead of client side routing.

```
var api = express.Router();
require('./app/routes')(api);
app.use('/api', api);
```

In your factory when we make a call as below this will go to server side routes.js rather than client side.

```
$resource('/api/adduser')
```

Comment: but how does the app decide if to use server side routes or client side routes  ?

Comment: By using this `app.use('/api', api);`
As mentioned in my answer. It checks if the url contains **/api** and if it has then it redirects it to routes on server side.